# Windows 7 Apache2.4 httpd.conf file

Tags: windows, apache

I'm running a windows server and my httpd.conf file got edited. Now my website at simonkurtisrhee.ddns.net does not work.

I'm not entirely sure how to post my httpd.conf file here. I am really new to this. If somebody could send me a default httpd.conf I could work from there, or if I could somehow post my code here that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this [Link](https://www.devside.net/guides/config/windows/httpd-conf). It has detailed explanation about the apache configuration including virtual hosts.

You can learn more about apache configuration settings and values [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html).

Comment: I am using 64 bit windows, would using the 32 bit httpd.conf file be a problem?

Comment: No, it will not be creating any such major issues known.

Comment: Wish I could, I only have 5 reputation and it says I need 15.  Once I get 15 I'll come back and upvote.

Comment: Now it is completely broken and no webpage appears and I have not changed anything.

Comment: @skrhee how come it got broken all of sudden ? It worked for 2 days and broken automatically ? Did you checked with your server support ? Is someone hacked your details?

Comment: I have no idea, I just redownloaded and started over